# Convert bytestring containing line breaks inside quotes to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

My target is to create a CSV file from an API call.
The problem is: The API returns a bytestring as content and I don't know how do convert it to a CSV file properly.

The content part of the response looks like this:

`b'column_title_1, column_title_2, column_title_3, value1_1, value1_2, value1_3\nvalue2_1, value2_2(="Perfect!\nThank you"), value2_3\n, value3_1, value3_2, value3_3\n....'`

How can I manage to get a clean CSV file from this? I tried Pandas, the CSV module and Numpy. Unfortunately, I was not able to handle the newline escapes which are sometimes within a string value (it is a column for comments) - see `value2_2`.

The result should look like this:

```
column_title_1, column_title_2, column_title_3
value1_1, value1_2, value1_3
value2_1, value2_2(="Perfect!\nThank you"), value2_3
value3_1, value3_2, value3_3
```

The closest of my results was this:

```
column_title_1, column_title_2, column_title_3
value1_1, value1_2, value1_3
value2_1, value2_2(="Perfect!
Thank you"), value2_3
value3_1, value3_2, value3_3
```

Even if I got close, I was not able to get rid of the `\n` within the values of some columns.
I did not figure out how to exclude the `\n` which are within `""`.

Comment: You should show your code attempt.  Use the 'csv' module.  `.decode('ascii')` (or whatever encoding the API uses) on your API response to make it a Unicode string that the 'csv.writer' accepts.  Seems like there should be a `\n` after `column_title_3` it the API data.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkTolonen! That what exactly the hint I was looking for! Did not see the wood for the trees :D...

Comment: Youi expected output seems like a needless complication. CSV can already express this structure, and Python's `csv` module knows how to read and write such a file, albeit as strings, not byte strings. If you need to be able to encode arbitrary bytes, the Latin-1 encoding does exactly that.